# SPARK SQL - case when then

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I'm new to SPARK-SQL. Is there an equivalent to "CASE WHEN 'CONDITION' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END" in SPARK SQL ?

`select case when 1=1 then 1 else 0 end from table`

Thanks
Sridhar

Comment: See answers to duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783517/apache-spark-add-an-case-when-else-calculated-column-to-an-existing-d

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**Before Spark 1.2.0**

The supported syntax (which I just tried out on Spark 1.0.2) seems to be

```
SELECT IF(1=1, 1, 0) FROM table
```

This recent thread http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Supported-SQL-syntax-in-Spark-SQL-td9538.html links to the SQL parser source, which may or may not help depending on your comfort with Scala. At the very least the list of keywords starting (at time of writing) on line 70 should help.

Here's the direct link to the source for convenience: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/SqlParser.scala.

**Update for Spark 1.2.0 and beyond**

As of Spark 1.2.0, the more traditional syntax is supported, in response to [SPARK-3813](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3813): search for "CASE WHEN" in the [test source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLQuerySuite.scala). For example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN key = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END FROM testData
```

**Update for most recent place to figure out syntax from the SQL Parser**

The parser source can now be found [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4).

**Update for more complex examples**

In response to a question below, the modern syntax supports complex Boolean conditions.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN id = 1 OR id = 2 THEN "OneOrTwo" ELSE "NotOneOrTwo" END AS IdRedux
FROM customer
```

You can involve multiple columns in the condition.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN id = 1 OR state = 'MA' 
         THEN "OneOrMA" 
         ELSE "NotOneOrMA" END AS IdRedux
FROM customer
```

You can also nest CASE WHEN THEN expression.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN id = 1 
         THEN "OneOrMA"
         ELSE
             CASE WHEN state = 'MA' THEN "OneOrMA" ELSE "NotOneOrMA" END
    END AS IdRedux
FROM customer
```

Comment: how can you add additional if statements to this such as extending with `or`. ie. `SELECT CASE WHEN key = 1 or key2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END FROM testData`

Comment: @horatio1701d The syntax of your example works for me (on Spark 2.1.0) as long as there is a column called key2 of the right type in testData. I added a bunch of examples of this [here](https://github.com/spirom/LearningSpark/blob/master/src/main/scala/sql/CaseWhenThen.scala) and have updated my answer accordingly. If you're having trouble making this work you may want to post a new question and link to it from here.

Comment: **@Spiro Michaylov**, does that mean for multiple `WHEN` clauses, we need to use **nested** `CASE WHEN .. ELSE WHEN`?

Answer (score 33):

**For Spark 2.+**
[Spark when function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#when)

From documentation:

> Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions. If otherwise is not defined at the end, null is returned for unmatched conditions.

```
 // Example: encoding gender string column into integer.

   // Scala:
   people.select(when(col("gender") === "male", 0)
     .when(col("gender") === "female", 1)
     .otherwise(2))

   // Java:
   people.select(when(col("gender").equalTo("male"), 0)
     .when(col("gender").equalTo("female"), 1)
     .otherwise(2))
```

Comment: Thanks Ehud! I used this approach to build a complex nested query with a few lines of code!

Answer (score 4):

This syntax worked for me in Databricks:

```
  select 
    org, 
    patient_id,
    case 
      when (age is null) then 'Not Available'
      when (age < 15) then 'Less than 15'
      when (age >= 15 and age < 25) then '15 to 25'
      when (age >= 25 and age < 35) then '25 to 35'
      when (age >= 35 and age < 45) then '35 to 45'
      when (age >= 45) then '45 and Older'
    end as age_range
  from demo
```

Answer (score 1):

The decode() function analog of Oracle SQL for SQL Spark can be implemented as follows:

```
​ case
​ ​ ​ when exp1 in ('a','b','c')
​ ​ ​ ​ then element_at(map('a','A','b','B','c','C'), exp1)
​ ​ ​ else exp1
​ ​ end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Based on my current production code, this works

   val identifierDF = 
   tempIdentifierDF.select(tempIdentifierDF("t_item_account_id"),
   when(tempIdentifierDF("h_description").contains(tempIdentifierDF("t_cusip")),100)
        .when(tempIdentifierDF("h_description").contains(tempIdentifierDF("t_ticker")),100)
        .when(tempIdentifierDF("h_description").contains(tempIdentifierDF("t_isin")),100)
        .when(tempIdentifierDF("h_description").contains(tempIdentifierDF("t_sedol")),100)
        .when(tempIdentifierDF("h_description").contains(tempIdentifierDF("t_valoren")),100)
        .otherwise(0)
        .alias("identifier_in_description_score")
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark DataFrame API (Python version) also enable to do next query:

```
df.selectExpr('time', \
   'CASE WHEN (time > 1) THAN time * 1.1 ELSE time END AS updated_time')
```