# Spark SQL: NULL handling in IF

Tags: sql, t-sql, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to perform `IF` [spark's coalesce] on top of a left outer joined output, but seems that `NULL` is not getting handled as expected. Here are my base tables, sample query, output and expected output-

Base tables:

> t1:
> a,100
> b,101
> c,102
>
> t2:
> 101

Query:

> select a.x, a.x1, IF(b.x1 is NULL,a.x1,b.x1) from t1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 b on a.x1=b.x1;

Output:

> a,100,null
> b,101,101
> c,102,null

Expected:

> a,100,100
> b,101,101
> c,102,102

I have also tried wrapping the above query and then performing an IF on top of it. But with no success. Please suggest is I am missing something.

Comment: Spark version? Spark 1.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working

File: tbl1

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

File: tbl2

```
1   c
3   d

case class c_tbl1(c1: String,c2: String)

sc.textFile("tbl1").map { row => 
val parts = row.split("\t")
c_tbl1(parts(0),parts(1)) }.registerTempTable("t_tbl1")

case class c_tbl2(c1: String,c2: String)

sc.textFile("tbl2").map { row => 
val parts = row.split("\t")
c_tbl2(parts(0),parts(1)) }.registerTempTable("t_tbl2")

sqlContext.sql("""select t.c1,t.c2,IF(t2.c1 is null,1,2),t2.c2 from t_tbl1 t left outer join t_tbl2 t2 on t.c1=t2.c1""".stripMargin).collect.foreach(println)


[1,a,2,c]
[2,b,1,null]
[3,c,2,d]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Case statement, not sure this CASE statement is supported by Spark SQL:-

```
select a.x, a.x1,
      CASE WHEN b.x1 IS NULL THEN a.x1
           ELSE b.x1
      END as bx1
from t1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 b on a.x1=b.x1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however CASE seems to be not supported by Spark at present. Ref: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157451/spark-sql-case-when-then)