# org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException while updating creating new RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns : `id` and `value`. I want to update the value based on another map.

```
 df.collect.foreach({
    df[value] = if (df[id] != 'unknown') mapper.value(df[id]) else df[value]
    })
```

Is this correct way of using ?

I tried :

```
import com.mapping.data.model.MappingUtils
import com.mapping.data.model.CountryInfo


val mappingPath = "s3://.../"    
val input = sc.textFile(mappingPath)
```

The input is list of jsons where each line is json which I am mapping to the POJO class CountryInfo using MappingUtils which takes care of JSON parsing and conversion:

```
val MappingsList = input.map(x=> {
                    val countryInfo = MappingUtils.getCountryInfoString(x);
                    (countryInfo.getItemId(), countryInfo)
                 }).collectAsMap

MappingsList: scala.collection.Map[String,com.mapping.data.model.CountryInfo] 


def showCountryInfo(x: Option[CountryInfo]) = x match {
      case Some(s) => s
   }


val events = sqlContext.sql( "select itemId  EventList")

val itemList =  events.map(row => {
    val itemId = row.getAs[String](1);
    val çountryInfo =  showTitleInfo(MappingsList.get(itemId));
    val country = if (countryInfo.getCountry() == 'unknown)' "US" else countryInfo.getCountry()
    val language = countryInfo.getLanguage()

    Row(itemId, country, language)
      })
```

But I keep getting this error :

```
    org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException at
 org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132) 
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84) at 

org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:362) at
 org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:284) at

 org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:191) at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:220) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:205) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:211) at 

org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93) at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:207) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:304) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using Spark 1.6

Comment: you should explain a bit more!

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto I want to update the column 'value' based on mapper

Comment: I don't get it, what mapper? what is the use of id? What is the df's schema?

Comment: Please check my answer! hope that helps

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Updated

Comment: Swetha : The above error which you added is related to some thing else (Thrift binary protocol) or zeepelin interpreter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is bit ambiguous.

> ## Don’t collect large RDDs unnecessarily.
>
> When a collect operation is issued on a RDD, the dataset is copied to
>   the driver, i.e. the master node. A memory exception will be thrown if
>   the dataset is too large to fit in memory; take or takeSample can be
>   used to retrieve only a capped number of elements instead.

The way you are doing by `collect` method is not correct(if it is large DataFrame it may lead to OOM)..

1) To update any column or add new column you can use `withColumn`

```
DataFrame   withColumn(java.lang.String colName, Column col)
Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.
```

2) To check the condition based on another datastructure..

you can use `when otherwise` syntax like below

[Apache Spark, add an "CASE WHEN ... ELSE ..." calculated column to an existing DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783517/apache-spark-add-an-case-when-else-calculated-column-to-an-existing-d)
[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357774/scala-how-can-i-replace-value-in-dataframs-using-scala) :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val sqlcont = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df1 = sqlcont.jsonRDD(sc.parallelize(Array(
      """{"year":2012, "make": "Tesla", "model": "S", "comment": "No Comment", "blank": ""}""",
      """{"year":1997, "make": "Ford", "model": "E350", "comment": "Get one", "blank": ""}""",
      """{"year":2015, "make": "Chevy", "model": "Volt", "comment": "", "blank": ""}"""
    )))

val makeSIfTesla = udf {(make: String) => 
  if(make == "Tesla") "S" else make
}
df1.withColumn("make", makeSIfTesla(df1("make"))).show
```

The above can be also achieved like this..

```
 val rdd = sc.parallelize(
      List( (2012,"Tesla","S"), (1997,"Ford","E350"), (2015,"Chevy","Volt"))
  )
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

  // this is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a DataFrame.
  import sqlContext.implicits._

  val dataframe = rdd.toDF()

  dataframe.foreach(println)

 dataframe.map(row => {
    val row1 = row.getAs[String](1)
    val make = if (row1.toLowerCase == "tesla") "S" else row1
    Row(row(0),make,row(2))
  }).collect().foreach(println)

//[2012,S,S]
//[1997,Ford,E350]
//[2015,Chevy,Volt]
```

Comment: It works with small queries but when I do complex I keep getting error

Comment: you mean to say using `collect` you are getting error with large data ?

Comment: @Swetha: The question was about approach of what you are doing using `collect` and other ways I explained... but this thrift error definitely not corelated error for this. I think you are using zeppelin... Its due to some other thing..