# How to add logic statement in the sql code?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a temp table where I have pulled in fields (that have multiple values that represent an attribute, now I want to create a logic where I compare these attributes and create a new field to summarize the ref_type and post_campaign field.

I am trying to create a new column (x) based on below logic/conditions:

```
> > if post_campaign starts with KNC-% and ref_type = 3 then create a new
column (x) with with field PS 
> > if post_campaign is null and ref_type = 3, then create a new column (x) with field OS 
> > if post_campaign starts with SNP-%, then create a new column (x) with field Pso 
> > if post_campaign starts with SNO-% and ref_type = 9, then create a new  column (x) with field OPso
> > if ref_type=6 then create a new column (x) with field Dir
```

I have created the temp table code, but need help on how do I insert the above logic in the sql query

```
create table temp.Register
Select date(date_time) as date, post_evar10, count(page_event) as Pageviews, concat(post_visid_high, post_visid_low) as UniqueVisitors, ref_type as Source_Traffic, paid_search, post_campaign
from a_hits
where ref_type in (3,6,7,9)
and ((post_evar10 like '%event-summary%') or (post_evar10 like 'registration-') or (post_evar10 like '%InformationPage%') or (post_evar10 like '%GuestRegInfo%') or (post_evar10 like '%GuestReg%') or post_evar10 like '%MyRegistration%'))
and page_event like '0'
and exclude_hit like '0'
and hit_source not in (5,7,8,9)
group by Date, post_evar10, UniqueVisitors, Source_Traffic, paid_search;
```

expected result will be a new column where I will see:

```
Date    Post_evar10 Pageviews   UniqueVisitors  Source_Traffic  post_campaign   Column X
2/2/2019    event-summary   540 200 3   KNC-%   PS
2/2/2019    event-summary   300 150 3   Null    OS
2/3/2019    event-summary   230 100 9   SNO-%   Opso
2/4/2019    event-summary   290 150 9   SNP-%   Pso
2/5/2019    event-summary   100 300 6   Misc    Dir
```

Comment: Does that query even work? You have two `FROM` clauses

Comment: is this for mysql or spark?

Comment: @JerryM.: It was a copy paste error.

Comment: @PatrickSmith: I am writing code in sql for databricks, so its sparksql.

Comment: Which version of `sparksql`? `1.2.0`?

Comment: @JerryM.its 2.11

Comment: Good. Then the posted solution should work for you. I don't have example data to test. though. Please let us know if it does not produce desired result.

Comment: Did it work? @NewCode

Comment: @JerryM. It not working I am getting a Parse Exception error at line 11, that is where the WHEN statement starts: Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'WHEN' expecting <EOF>(line 11, pos 8)

== SQL ==
create table temp.Register
Select 
    date(date_time) as Date, 
    post_evar10, 
    count(page_event) as Pageviews, 
    concat(post_visid_high, post_visid_low) as UniqueVisitors, 
    ref_type as Source, 
    post_campaign
    -- Inclusion here
    CASE
        WHEN post_campaign LIKE 'KNC-%' AND ref_type = 3 THEN 'Paid Search'
--------^^^

Comment: Try it now. @NewCode

Comment: @jerryM: the code works, thankyou for your help.

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer as "Accepted" so that it may help others :) @NewCode

Comment: Please don't forget to mark this correct @NewCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [newest version of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157451/spark-sql-case-when-then) `sparksql`, you can utilize a `CASE...WHEN` statement

Learn more about `CASE...WHEN` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

```
create table temp.Register

Select 
    date(date_time) as the_date, 
    post_evar10, 
    count(page_event) as Pageviews, 
    concat(post_visid_high, post_visid_low) as UniqueVisitors, 
    ref_type as Source_Traffic, 
    paid_search, 
    post_campaign,
    CASE
        WHEN post_campaign LIKE 'KNC-%' AND ref_type = 3 THEN 'PS'
        WHEN post_campaign IS NULL AND ref_type = 3 THEN 'OS'
        WHEN post_campaign LIKE 'SNP-%' THEN 'PSO'
        WHEN post_campaign LIKE 'SNO-%' AND ref_type = 9 THEN 'Opso'
        WHEN ref_type = 6 THEN 'Dir'
    ELSE NULL END AS Column_X
from 
    a_hits

where 
    ref_type in (3,6,7,9)
    and ((post_evar10 like '%event-summary%') or (post_evar10 like 'registration-') or (post_evar10 like '%InformationPage%') or (post_evar10 like '%GuestRegInfo%') or (post_evar10 like '%GuestReg%') or post_evar10 like '%MyRegistration%'))
    and page_event like '0'
    and exclude_hit like '0'
    and hit_source not in (5,7,8,9)

group by 
    the_Date, 
    post_evar10, 
    UniqueVisitors, 
    Source_Traffic, 
    paid_search
;
```