# Spark SQL equivalent for Oracle functions

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find the spark SQL for the following oracle function

```sql
IIF(ISNULL(TYPE_CODE),'UNASSIGNED',TYPE_CODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In scala :**

```
import  org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => f} 
val new_df = df_name.withColumn("col_name",f.when(f.col("other_col_name").isNull(),TYPE_CODE)
```

Comment: I want it in spark sql

Comment: Use this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157451/spark-sql-case-when-then