# Creating a column if a condition is proven to be true

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I want to create a column called "quelle" filled with a lit("XY") if another column contains a certain substring. The code I wrote like this:

```scala
df => df.withColumn("quelle", when(substring_of_other_column.contains("123"), lit("XY")))
```

But i get the error:
Type mismatch: Required column, found boolean.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what is element_quelle?

Comment: @mck its the substring of the other column. i edited it

Comment: what's the type of substring_of_other_column? is it a column? a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SPARK SQL - case when then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157451/spark-sql-case-when-then)

Comment: @mck it is a string

Answer (score 2):

`df.withColumn("quelle",when(col("id").contains("123"),lit("XY")).otherwise("AA"))`
should give you the result you are looking for

I tried to reproduce the error you are getting and this is likely the one which you tried
df.withColumn("quelle",when("id".contains("123"),lit("XY")).otherwise("AA")) which gives me exactly the same error you are getting above.

error: type mismatch;
found   : Boolean
required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Please check if this helps

Comment: bro can we get married, thank you. it works now. 
 could you explain to me what the problem was? im a scala noob so it'd be nice to know (:

Comment: 'when' accepts a column as argument, so you must include col("col_name") or $"col_name" instead of just col_name                                                                    
-- def when(condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value: Any)

Comment: @marryTheEngineer, if you are new to scala, a couple of things in this situation might help, scala is strong type language, type must match. Try to use an IDE such as IntelliJ to “```ctrl+b```” on you code to go and find the underlying signature definition, it shows you the function parameter type requirements clearly.