# Spark sql parse exception

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am trying to execute sql query through spark sql. In oracle this query works without problems but in spark.sql I get error:

[image]

spark version - 0.2.1

SQL:

```
SELECT
a.*,
( a.clc_1 + a.clc_2 + a.clc_3 ) / 3 AS arpu,
CASE WHEN limit_max is null THEN CASE
                          WHEN break_$ < 1
                          OR break_$ IS NULL THEN 0.01
                          ELSE break_$ END
WHEN limit_max < 1
   OR limit_max IS NULL THEN 0.01
ELSE limit_max
END AS old_limit
FROM def.FEAUTRES_TEST_1  a
```

Could this be due to a syntax difference? And how can it be fixed?

Comment: And why did you tag this with oracle? I mean if it works in oracle, what can oracle guys do for you here?

Comment: The answer seems to depend on your Spark version - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157451/spark-sql-case-when-then?rq=1

Comment: (sorry for the dupe hammer, I forgot that it was tagged as Oracle which resulted in an insta-close by me. I've removed the Oracle tag, since the question really is not related to Oracle)